# Saving state of services in Linux services in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to save whether services are in running state or stopped. I applied the following login.

```
---
- hosts: all

  vars:
    myName: Nikunj
    result: ""

  tasks:
  - name: Initialize empty Started and Stopped list of strings
    set_fact:
      started: []
      stopped: []

  - name: Saving context of the VM
    shell: service tomcat status
    ignore_errors: true
    register: result
    when: ' "running" in "{{result.stdout}}" '
    set_fact:
      started : "{{ started }} + ['tomcat']"

  - debug:
      msg: "{{started}}"
```

shell command here is giving me eroor.

Comment: split `shell` and `set_fact` tasks

Answer (score 1):

```
---
- hosts: all

  vars:
    myName: Nikunj
    result: ""

  tasks:
  - name: Initialize empty Started and Stopped list of strings
    set_fact:
      started: []
      stopped: []

  - name: Saving context of the VM
    shell: service tomcat status
    ignore_errors: true
    register: result

  - name: setting fact  
    set_fact:
      started : "{{ started }} + ['tomcat']"
    when: ' "running" in "{{result.stdout}}" '

  - debug:
      msg: "{{started}}"
```

This will work. set_fact is an individual module.

Comment: `when` should be attached to `set_fact`, not `shell`; wrong braces usage in `when` statement, should be raw expression; braces are misplaced in `set_fact` task; this all should be evident from error messages that OP hasn't posted.